# 'Forms' is not a member of 'Windows'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5.2

I tried to change the Target Framework on my app recently from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.5.2, but if I do I get the following error when trying to build: "'Forms' is not a member of 'Windows'" (that is, `System.Windows.Forms`). Changing to 4.5.1 works normally. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: 4.5.2?  Is this a beta or RC?

Comment: Nope, it is a official release, 4 days ago.

Answer (score 41):

I had this error when changing to 4.5.2.

In my case the error was related to a MessageBox ... I replaced: "Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes" (which caused the same error message) with "System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes" which did the trick.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, me too with `Windows.Forms.DialogResult` enumeration values.

The project automatically imports `System` and `System.Windows.Forms` namespaces and worked fine up to `4.5.1`.

In `4.5.2` I had to remove `Windows.Forms.` and just leave `DialogResult.Ok` (or whatever else) in my code, it seems to be a problem with namespaces resolution.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you add `System` in front of the `Windows.Form`.

Comment: Some clarification of the steps would be helpful here.

Comment: This is exactly what the [answer posted a year prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443406/11683) suggests.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this with an application still targeted to .NET 4.0, where it failed on one (new) build server, but ran on my older ones.

I narrowed it down to the .NET 4.0 Targeting Pack only being installed on the old build servers. Targeting pack is included in Visual Studio, or the Windows 7.1 SDK. It is for some reason not distributed separately, and with [support ending for .NET 4, 4.5 and 4.5.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/), I don't suspect this is likely to change. Because my older servers have been around a couple years, they've gone through in-place upgrades and so had the targeting pack already.

When you install Windows 7.1 SDK on Server 2012R2, it complains something to the effect of "A pre-release version of .NET 4 is installed, please install the RTM version". As far as I can tell, it's simply because a newer version) is installed -- Server 2012R2 comes with 4.5.1. I tried to uninstall all newer versions, but was unable to get the SDK to install the targeting pack.

So to install:

- Download the [Windows 7.1 SDK ISO image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=8279)
- Unzip it
- Run `Setup\MTPack\netfx_dtp.msi EXTUI=1`

You should now have a `%programfiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\` folder with the 4.0 stuff.

(EXTUI=1 bypasses the restriction that it can't be [installed separately](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225240%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

This allowed me to compile projects still targeting 4.0 (or re-build old revisions/branches that were targeting it at the time).